# Does MongoClient.getDatabase() return just a DB instance or actually creates it?

Tags: java, mongodb

In order to create a database instance in MongoDB 3.2 you have to write something like that:

```java
new MongoClient().getDatabase("dbName");
```

According to the official [MongoDB Java API 3.2](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#getDatabase-java.lang.String-) this should return you a database instance.

My questions:

1. Do I understand correctly, that if the DB with the specified name does not exist, thus MongoDB will create it for me?
2. And if the assumption from the question #1 is correct, what will happen if I'll try to request the same DB twice? Will it return just the already existed instance or will drop the existed one and will create a new one?

P.S. Can you, please, advise me a good and *updated* MongoDB for Java manual/tutorial, I googled for a couple of them, but they are not so updated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `3.1.1` driver:

Calling `getDatabase` doesn't in fact create new database because operation is lazy - it returns database representation. Calling any modifiable operation (e.g. `createCollection`):

1. will create new database for you if it is not present
2. if present it will get database for you

But remember that you have to call any operation which actually performs something - like create. If you just call `getDatabase` it won't create it.

Comment: Point 1 explicitly states that it will create a new database, but then you end by explicitly saying that it wont because its lazy. Can you please clarify point 1 to reflect this.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I edited my answer, is it acceptable now?

Comment: Yep, much better +1 :)

Comment: Great, thank you so much.
I spent quite a lot of time to understand how to force the `MongoDB` to *really* create the DB with the `getDatabase()`. It's a pity that the official API documentation doesn't clarify such thin moments in an explicit way.