# how can i create mongodb database from java

Tags: java, mongodb

I can drop a database with the following statement:

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
mongo.dropDatabase("d");
```

How can I create a database?

Comment: Did you really need to copy-paste your question 3 times without formatting? People won't want to deal with your question if looks like that. (Note to others: See edit revisions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB("database name");
```

If database is not present, MongoDB will create it for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using driver 3.1.1 or later:

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33902555/1754020):

> Calling getDatabase doesn't in fact create new database because
>   operation is lazy - it returns database representation. Calling any
>   modifiable operation (e.g. createCollection):
>
> will create new database for you if it is not present if present it
>   will get database for you But remember that you have to call any
>   operation which actually performs something - like create. If you just
>   call getDatabase it won't create it.

**NOTE**

The [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#getDatabase-java.lang.String-) does not provide this information, hopefully, they update it. But long answer short, it only creates it after you call an operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create MongoDB database from java with the following code it will be successful but one catch a Mongo database should contain a single collection to display the database while querying.

```
`MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(CONNECTION_URL);
    System.out.println("Connection with database established successfully");`
    
    String databaseName = "SK_BANK_LTD";
    
    System.out.println("Trying to create a database :- "+databaseName);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(databaseName);
```

By running the following code the database wont be visible as it does not contain any collection so add a dummy collection in the database while creating a database by `MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(CONNECTION_URL);
System.out.println("Connection with database established successfully");

```
    String databaseName = "SK_BANK_LTD";
    
    System.out.println("Trying to create a database :- "+databaseName);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(databaseName);
    
    Document test = new Document().append("createdBy", "Binson");
    db.getCollection("test").insertOne(test);
    
    System.out.println("Database: " + databaseName + "created successfully");`
```

Make sure your database does not contain the following characters which are prohibited by mongoDB.

'\0', '/', '\', ' ', '"', '.'